# Jasmine/JavaScript: Test that a new object was created

Tags: javascript, jasmine

My goal it to assert that `new Bassist()` was called by the `start()` method **and** create a mock object, instead.

This the second test is currently failing with the error "Expected spy constructor to have been called."

```js
class Bassist {
  constructor() {
    console.log('bassist joined')
  }
}

class Drummer {
  constructor() {
    console.log('drummer joined')
  }
}

class Band {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
    this.bassist = null
    this.drummer = null
  }

  start() {
    this.bassist = new Bassist()
    this.drummer = new Drummer()
  }
}

describe('Band', () => {
  describe('start()', () => {
    it('sets the bassist property', () => {
      let band = new Band('The Foobars')
      band.start()
      expect(band.bassist).not.toBeNull()
    })

    it('creates a new bassist', () => {
      spy = spyOn(Bassist.prototype, 'constructor')
      band = new Band('The Foobars')
      band.start()
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
      console.log('expect was called')
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Specs</title>

  <!-- Jasmine v2.5.2 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine.css"></link>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/boot.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error (and searching), I wasn't able to override the call to `new Bassist()` and replace it with a spy object. Instead, I created a separate method within the Band class to handle Bassist object creation, and then put a spy on it.

Who knows if this is good practice, but it works for me.

```js
class Bassist {
  constructor() {
    console.log('bassist joined')
  }
}

class Band {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
    this.bassist = null
  }

  start() {
    this.bassist = this.createBassist()
  }

  createBassist() {
    return new Bassist()
  }
}

describe('Band', () => {
  let band, createBassistSpy, bassistSpy

  beforeEach(() => {
    // setup spies
    bassistSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('bassist', ['shred', 'quit', 'otherSickMethod'])
    createBassistSpy = spyOn(Band.prototype, 'createBassist')
     .and.returnValue(bassistSpy)

    // init subject being tested
    band = new Band('The Foobars')
  })

  describe('new', () => {
    it('initializes bassist to null', () => {
      expect(band.bassist).toBe(null)
    })
  })

  describe('start()', () => {
    it('calls the createBassist() method', () => {
      band.start()
      expect(createBassistSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()

      // Not a great test, but ensures we are working with the
      // bassistSpy object, and not something else.
      expect(band.bassist).toEqual(bassistSpy)
    })

    it('sets the bassist property', () => {
      band.start()
      expect(band.bassist).not.toBeNull()
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Specs</title>

  <!-- Jasmine v2.5.2 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine.css"></link>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/boot.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `band.start` is not actually calling `Bassist.prototype.constructor` (which should be replaced by the spy), but rather is calling `Bassist` (which is not the spy).

The only way you could make it spy on `Bassist` would be to actually replace `Bassist` on that lexical scope.

Comment: How might I go about doing this? Is there a better way to test that the `start()` method creates a new Bassist object?

Comment: It'd be very hard to spy on it (if they are on separate scopes). I'd just test that `band.drummer` is actually an object that's instance of `Bassist`

Comment: If they are on same scope, then just replace `Bassist` with the `spy` (`Bassist = spy`). I'd assume spyOn to return the `spy` but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

For checking if constructor was called you can check result of [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator

```js
class Bassist {
  constructor() {
    console.log('bassist joined')
  }
}

class Drummer {
  constructor() {
    console.log('drummer joined')
  }
}

class Band {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
    this.bassist = null
    this.drummer = null
  }

  start() {
    this.bassist = new Bassist()
    this.drummer = new Drummer()
  }
}

describe('Band', () => {
  describe('start()', () => {
    it('sets the bassist property', () => {
      let band = new Band('The Foobars')
      band.start()
      expect(band.bassist).not.toBeNull()
    })

    it('creates a new bassist', () => {
      let band = new Band('The Foobars')
      band.start()
      expect(band.bassist instanceof Bassist).toBeTruthy()
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine.css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/boot.js"></script>
```

Helpful for solving testing issue can be `dependency injection` pattern. Consider that Bassist contructor calls some `allSortOfOtherCode` method. You can spy on it and verify that was executed.

```js
class Bassist {
  constructor() {
    console.log('bassist joined')
    this.allSortOfOtherCode()
  }

  allSortOfOtherCode() {

  }
}

class Drummer {
  constructor() {
    console.log('drummer joined')
  }
}

class Band {
  constructor(name, bassist, drummer) {
    this.name = name
    this.bassist = bassist
    this.drummer = drummer
  }

  start() {
    this.bassist = new this.bassist()
    this.drummer = new this.drummer()
  }
}

describe('Band', () => {
  describe('start()', () => {
    it('creates a new bassist', () => {
      let band = new Band('The Foobars', Bassist, Drummer)
      expect(band.bassist instanceof Bassist).toBeFalsy()
      band.start()
      expect(band.bassist instanceof Bassist).toBeTruthy()
    })

    it('creates bassist from passed object', () => {
      let bassist = jasmine.createSpy('bassist')
      let band = new Band('The Foobars', bassist, Drummer)
      expect(bassist).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
      band.start()
      expect(bassist).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })

    it('calls `allSortOfOtherStuff()`', function() {
      spyOn(Bassist.prototype, 'allSortOfOtherCode')
      let band = new Band('The Foobars', Bassist, Drummer)
      band.start()
      expect(Bassist.prototype.allSortOfOtherCode).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine.css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/boot.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! That is helpful. I also need to have the call to `new Bassist()` return a Jasmine spy object.

Comment: What you want to achive by returning spy from calling new?.

Comment: Separation of concerns. Imagine that creating a new Bassist kicked off all sorts of other code. I want to test that a call to `new Bassist()` was made, and prevent any further code execution by the constructor.

Comment: Please take a look into latest edited example and how to test that "all sorts of other code" was executed …

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the exact Jasmine setup from the question, so this should actually apply to all versions since the question was asked, even if it was more than five years ago.

The trick is to replace Bassist with a function that can be spied on. Since it's JS and you can `new` a `function`, we'll just replace the `Bassist` class with a function, spy on the function, and return the actual `Bassist` after.

On TypeScript, this should even satisfy the need for the fake to return a correct Bassist. If you're trying to inject a `FakeBassist` that plays only air guitar, define the class and return the instance with `as unknown as Bassist` to ignore the typing.

```js
class Bassist {
  constructor() {
    console.log('bassist joined');
  }
}

class Drummer {
  constructor() {
    console.log('drummer joined');
  }
}

class Band {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.bassist = null;
    this.drummer = null;
  }

  start() {
    this.bassist = new Bassist();
    this.drummer = new Drummer();
  }
}

describe('Band', () => {
  describe('start()', () => {
    it('sets the bassist property', () => {
      let band = new Band('The Foobars');
      band.start();
      expect(band.bassist).not.toBeNull();
    })

    it('creates a new bassist', () => {
      const originalBassist = Bassist;
      Bassist = jasmine.createSpy('Bassist').and.callFake(function() {
        console.log('fake constructor');
        return new originalBassist();
      });
      const band = new Band('The Foobars');
      band.start();
      expect(Bassist).toHaveBeenCalled();
      console.log('expect was called');
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Specs</title>

  <!-- Jasmine v2.5.2 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine.css"></link>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/boot.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

As a side note, I was struggling with a `WebSocket` replacement, which I finally injected like this:

```
  beforeAll(() => {
    spyOn(window, 'WebSocket').and.callFake(function (url, protocols) {
      return new MockWebSocket(url, protocols) as unknown as WebSocket;
    });
  });
```